# Xcode iOS: UITabBar update objects while switching to another tab

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I want an action, that starts when the user is switching the tabs in a UITabBarController so I can update the labels and stuff on the View the user is switching to. Do you guys know any action, that does this thing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method is called, when a tab is switched in UITabBar:

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

This is delegate method of `UITabBarDelegate` protocol.

Comment: Do I have to put this method in the UITabBarController-Class or the UIView that will appear?

Comment: in the UITabBarController-Class, I got it thank you very much